# Finding a minimum covering of a polygon with interesting shapes

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, computational-geometry, covering

After reading many papers about problems of minimum [polygon covering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_covering), I found out that there are four different types of units that are considered for covering polygons, in increasing order of generality: squares, rectangles, convex shapes and star shapes.

In theory, there can be many other covering units, for example: it is possible to cover a polygon with triangles (this is different than the problem of triangulation because the units in a covering may overlap), pentagons, hexagons... but, I haven't found any paper discussing such covering problems.

My question is: are you aware of any papers discussing the problem of finding a minimum covering of a polygon with shapes other than the four classes above?

I am particularly interested in covering a polygon with right-angled isosceles triangles, isolateral triangles or other regular polygons.

[NOTE: Cross-posted from cs.SE after I received the Tumbleweed badge for it]

Comment: Also covering by *spirals* were considered in this paper:  O'Rourke, J.; Supowit, K. (1983). "Some NP-hard polygon decomposition problems". *IEEE Transactions on Information Theory* 29 (2): 181.

Comment: Also partitions into L-shapes have been studied, but I do not recall work on *covers* by L-shapes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a recent paper by Tobias Christ that extends the covering work I cited in
the comments, and work by Andrejz Lingas, to triangles, one of the problems left
unresolved by that earlier work.
Tobias shows, via an intricate construction, 
that the minimum cover of a simple polygon by triangles
is also NP-hard:

> Christ, Tobias. "Beyond triangulation: covering polygons with triangles." *Algorithms and Data Structures*. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2011. 231-242. ([Springer link](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-22300-6_20))

The paper also contains a nice, up-to-date summary of work in this area.

---

[image: TobiasFig1]

 
 
 
Christ Fig.1: Gadgets in the NP-hardness construction.